# Как хранить похожие сущности в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql, нормализация-данных

Мне нужно хранить много похожих данных о моей системе вопросов и ответов, таких как голосование, подписка, закладки и т. д.

В качестве примера голосования, каков наилучший макет таблицы для хранения голосов за вопросы, ответы и посты?

1. Хранить голоса отдельно, то есть получается 3 таблицы: UserQuestionVotes, UserAnswerVotes и UserPostVotes
2. Хранить голоса в одной таблице:
   UserVotes (id, user_id, item_id, item_type, vote),
   тогда как: item_id и item_type - это идентификатор и тип вопроса, ответа или поста, vote = -1/1

В первом случае, у меня будет как минимум 9 таблиц.
И если я пойду вторым путем, то есть все данные будут в одной куче, считаю в будущем при заполнении таблицы она будет работать медленнее.

Какой способ в моем случае эффективен с точки зрения производительности/скорости?

Comment: В вашем случае нет эффективного способа, не учтены такие вещи как частота событий(голосование\отмена голоса), частота событий(чтение\запись), Необходимая аналитика\пересчет голосов\....

Comment: Зы. еще кое что дополню, на какие объемы данных вы расчитываете(1ккк+ записей?) Что важней - скорость вставки\чтения? какой сложности запросы вы собираетесь использовать на таблицах? зы. join - дорогая операция, зачастую гораздо дороже чем выбрать несколько ненужных вам полей из одной таблицы =)

Comment: И как их надо учитывать? Объем данных будет в среднем 1м, операции простые вставка/удаление/сумма. Важнее скорость чтения то есть суммирования, как полагаю.

Comment: Я склоняюсь к первому варианту.

Comment: Эмм... Либо вы меня не поняли, либо я вас, вы не написали как именно собираетесь потом работать с данными, что для вас важнее быстро записывать или быстро выбирать? Что важнее меньше места в озу\диске или скорость доступа... и еще множество вещей которые влияют на правильный выбор структуры БД.
@Z.John а я ко второму, но это не аргументированный ответ который может только сделать хуже без понимания что именно нужно автору вопроса =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо за ответ, для меня важнее быстро выбирать и скорость доступа, в этом и заключается суть моего вопроса. Мне самому хочется объединить все в одну кучу (одну таблицу) но боюсь что в дальнейшем при заполнении таблицы запросы будут выполнятся медленнее.

Comment: Тогда ваш вариант второй, может занимать чуть больше места из за избыточности данных на каждый голос, но при этом выборка без join всегда будет быстрей, если добавите сразу возможность партицирования - будет прям быстро(опыт на таблице в пол террабайта и почти 2млрд записей), если правильно расставлять ключи(индексы) и оптимизировать запросы, хотя до 1миллиона записей даже выборками select * from table; - не положите адекватный сервер.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков благодарю за расширенный ответ, буду проектировать по второму варианту, с учетем партицирования, индексирования и оптимизации запросов.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Меня смущает здесь фраза `выборка без join всегда будет быстрей`, кому в такой таблице нужна выборка без join? Допустим мне надо загрузить список вопросов 1000 вопросов с их рейтингами... как тогда?  И за счет чего запросы к одной общей таблице которая в 9 раз больше (по словам автора) будут проходить быстрее чем к отдельной таблице которая в 10 раз меньше? Во всех запросах появится дополнительный параметр отбора item_type. При каждой записи будет дополнительно перестраиваться индекс по item_type... Есть сомнения, что второй вариант быстрее первого и в плане чтения и записи.

Comment: @Z.John Ок, перефразирую, join по 4 таблицам(первый вариант) будет всегда медленней join'a по 2м таблицам(второй вариант). 2) Перестроение индекса идет в отдельно от запросов в pgsql(vacum analayze\full\...) сложность join растет в геометрической прогрессии от размера данных (`count(table1.id)*count(table2.id)`), в то время как выборка из одной таблицы имеет линейную сложность от кол-ва данных. т.е. выборка из двух таблиц в которых по 100 записей будет равна 100*100, в то время как такая же точно сложность будет при одной таблице и 10к записей, все что описано немного упрощено для понимания.

Comment: @Z.John все что я здесь описывал совпадает с теорией баз данных и личными наблюдениями. Бывают случаи когда join таблиц происходит за дешего, например при join'e таблицы которая полностью находится в памяти(обычно полностью в память помещают таблицы подстановки, в которых пара десятков записей)

Comment: Решите всё же, это разные сущности (каждая со своим набором атрибутов и процессов), или одна сущность, просто набор непустых, имеющих значение, атрибутов различается. Только это и должно быть основой решения.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков >join по 4 таблицам(первый вариант) будет всегда медленней join'a по 2м таблицам(второй вариант) - с этим я абсолютно согласен. Вот только не понимаю зачем может понадобиться джойнить рейтинги разных сущностей одновременно. Есть допустим отдельно таблица Вопросов к ней джойнить только один конкретный рейтинг где item_type = question_id...

Comment: @Z.John, потому что я упорот полностью, и прочел названия таблиц совершенно неверно, вы правы, первый вариант будет лучше, второй - с доработкой до сквозных айди(убрать поля id, item_type) поле id -  не имеет смысла(уникальным является user_id + item_id), поле item_type - не будет иметь смысла если не использовать партицирование по нему, и использовать сквозные айди.... Я почему то вдолбил себе в голову что там(в вопросе) таблицы вида Users,Users_info,....

Comment: @IbnAdam  разобрались :)

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант предпочтительней

> Хранить голоса отдельно, то есть получается 3 таблицы: UserQuestionVotes, UserAnswerVotes и UserPostVotes

таблицы будут в 9 раз меньше, запросы будут проще и скорости чтения/записи будут быстрее по сравнению со вторым вариантом.

PS:читайте комментарии к вопросу

Comment: Плюс в "карму", но в 9 раз вы загнули, разница в размере таблиц будет от нуля(вырождение системы где голосуют только в одну сущность) до бесконечности(обратная ситуация, для вырожденного случая(0 записей в одну из таблиц)), но в среднем в 3 раза меньше, учитывая те оптимизации о которых я говорил в комментариях под вопросом(убрать 2 лишних поля).